# Assertion failed while creating Menu Item Label in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am building a game in cocos2dx in which i have to create menu item label. I am creating them in a loop and then adding them in menu:

```
 auto menuForNumberButtons = Menu::create();
    menuForNumberButtons->setPosition(Vec2(0,0));
    this->addChild(menuForNumberButtons, 3);
    for (int  yy = 0; yy < 3; yy++ )
    {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < 3; xx++) 
        {
            counterOfNumers++;

            MenuItemLabel *numberButton=MenuItemLabel::create(Label::createWithTTF(String::createWithFormat("%d",counterOfNumers)->getCString(), "arial.ttf", visibleSize.width*0.05), this, menu_selector(BSHSuDokuKeypad::numberButtonPressed));
            numberButton->setScaleX(widthOfNumberCell*0.5 / numberButton->getBoundingBox().size.width);
            numberButton->setScaleY(heightOfNumberCell*0.5 / numberButton->getBoundingBox().size.height);
            numberButton->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width*0.005+widthOfNumberCell*xx + numberButton->getBoundingBox().size.width*0.5,  visibleSize.height*0.7+  heightOfNumberCell*yy + numberButton->getBoundingBox().size.height*0.5));
            menuForNumberButtons->addChild(numberButton);}}
```

but when i click on any number. it gives me an error saying assertion failed without calling the callback function. 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like some precondition/ postcondition is failing when some function is called. Since you're dealing with quite a few objects, I'm betting that your issue originates in the failed creation of your MenuItemLabel.
I'd recommend further inspection of this line:

```
MenuItemLabel *numberButton=MenuItemLabel::create(Label::createWithTTF(String::createWithFormat("%d",counterOfNumers)->getCString(), "arial.ttf", visibleSize.width*0.05), this, menu_selector(BSHSuDokuKeypad::numberButtonPressed));
```

Now, I'm not familiar with this language so I can't tell you much about syntax but looking at the API I've discovere that this line format should be formatted:

```
static MenuItemLabel *  create (Node *label, Ref *target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
```

Wish I could do more for ya, but hopefully I pointed you in the direction of progress

Comment: Syntax is correct. Plus menu item label creation is fine i.e. i can see them on screen. the problem is some what with menu_selector. anyways thanks a lot

Comment: Interesting, what methods are called when you click on one of the numbers?

Comment: numberButtonPressed is called

Comment: hmm, well to me the error seems to imply that the big issue is the failure of some method's precondition/ postcondition. Since you say the NULL the objects are created fine, perhaps there's something else wrong with at least one inputs/ data numberButtonPressed() processes. Sounds like an attribute of one these processed objects fails to meet some necessary criteria of numberButtonPressed(). You're more familiar with this lanuage, does this seem possible?